# How to tell whether an XML Node has only a text node underneath?

Tags: scala

I am working on a function, the goal is to return text node's text if the text node is an element's only child. For example:

`<root>1</root> => 1`

`<root><node>1</node></root> => null`

Apparently Scala does not distinguish between a Node with only text and Node with an element.

So how can I tell if an element (or generically, a Node) has only a text node underneath it?

Comment: Note that entity references are also nodes, so that e.g. `<root>a&lt;b</root>` does _not_ have only one text node child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power of pattern matching:

```
import xml.{Text, Elem, Node}

def extractText(n: Node): String = n match {
    case Elem(_, _, _, _, Seq(Text(t))) => t
    case _ => null
}

println(extractText(<root>1</root>))
println(extractText(<root><node>1</node></root>))
```

But more scala-way is to return `Option[String]` instead of `String/null`:

```
def extractText(n: Node): Option[String] = n match {
    case Elem(_, _, _, _, Seq(Text(t))) => Some(t)
    case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Text` and `Elem` are both XML Nodes, thus identifying type of node can be achieved by `isInstanceOf`, for an example:

```
import scala.xml.{Text, Node}
def hasOnlyTextChild(node:Node) = node.child.size == 1 && node.child(0).isInstanceOf[Text]
```

Comment: Pattern matching is almost always preferable to an overt `isInstanceOf`, even though the `case foo: Foo =>` form is equivalent to combining `isInstanceOf` with `asInstanceOf`.